# clickable drawable inside EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, drawable, android-edittext

I have an EditText with a drawable inside. I want to make the drawable clickable so that I can have a specific action when user clicks the drawable. How do I do that? My EditText is:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/question_mark"
        android:hint="phone number"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/phone_num"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: Why `EditText` not `ImageView`? Add an `android:onClick="phoneClicked"` attribute, then implement `public void phoneClicked( View view ) {...}`.

Comment: My design asks that the question_mark image appear inside the EditText view.

Comment: Gotcha, as far as I am aware, you cannot do that, you would have to make a container with white background and add EditText and an Image beside it, and make the Image onClick. In other words, you would give the illusion that the image is inside the Text area, but in reality, it is not. If anyone knows I am wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: RelativeLayout might be able to allow you put button up/down to the EditText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gina suggested above, you can achieve this by using RelativeLayout instead of drawableRight property. Code below puts the imageview to the right part of your EditText

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:hint="phone number"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/phone_num"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know how to do this. I was looking for something simpler. But until someone shows a better answer, I'll accept this one.

Comment: This doesn't work properly, the text goes under the image. Not exceptable in high standard apps.

Comment: it works properly.. if you give the edittext 40dp of padding from right(for the code i gave) text will be finishing before the image and they will not collapse.

Comment: You can also do  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" keep it match parent

Answer (score 1):

```
phone.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(motionEvent.getRawX() >= (phone.getRight() - phone.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    //Here is your code when you click drawable right
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```