# How to add a view inside of an editText? (such as when tagging users)

Tags: android, layout, view, tags, textview

I'm working on an application that should allow the user to tag a user onto an item. In Google Drive, for example, when you're entering users to send an item to, the user's name becomes it's own "view" in the textview so that it cannot be modified and broken.

My current implementation already contains an autocomplete registry of current users, and formats the usernames with html tags so that they're interpreted correctly by the backend, but it's still possible to tamper by moving the cursor to the center of the name and modifying it.

I would like at least an example of how to accomplish what I am trying to do. The problem itself is hard to search for, probably because I just don't know what to call it.

Example of what I'm looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbtxI.jpg

Comment: Have you looked at custom views at all? What you're saying might be solved by implementing a custom editText with embeded TextView, probably inside of a relative view so you can "stack them" it might take a lot of custom work but should be able to be accomplished..

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558072/clickable-drawable-inside-edittext-in-android

Comment: @aminner I figured I'd have to do something like that. I browsed a lot of third party libraries for a while to see if I could find a similar implementation, but it's been a bit annoying not knowing what to call it so that I can search for it.

Comment: @ghassen92 That is not what I'm looking for, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I came accross this: https://plus.google.com/+RichHyndman/posts/TSxaARVsRjF

Seeing that they're called "chips" is making this a lot more researchable. I'm still a bit weary about what I'm going to do, but I've got enough resources to start.

I'm going to attempt to make a LinearLayout that dynamically contains "chips" and edittext views and handles most of the functions of an edit texts.

Comment: Good luck! I'd also be curious to see what you're able to come up with.